# what is the equivalant to MbUnit.Framework.RowAttribute in MSTest?

Tags: mstest

Which is the equivalent to `MbUnit.Framework.RowAttribute` in MSTest?

I want to feed an MSTest `TestMethod` with different data. In `MBUit` it is dead simple:

```
[Row("foo", "bar", "foo bar")]
[Row("fat", "cat", "fat cat")]
[Row("wise", "geek", "wise geek")]
[Test]
public void TestMyConcat(string first, string second, string expected)
{
   string actual = MyConcat(first, second);
   Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

How is this done in MSTest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no direct equivalent provided in MSTest.

The closest thing is a [Data Driven Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx) which pulls its data from an external file.